# Using Coulomb's law to solve for a continuous charge distribution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

I have been trying to evaluate this specific integral and have been completely stuck. $$\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \int^L_0  \frac{2\lambda z}{(x^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}dx.$$

I am a freshman and have been studying ahead in my own time but, I've hit a wall. Do I need to make some trig substitution here in order to be able to evaluate this integral properly? I fear I'm a bit out of my league here but I was wondering if anyone would be so humble as to give me a nudge in the correct direction or even walk me through how I should go about solving this for

$$\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}   \frac{2\lambda L}{z\sqrt{L^2+z^2}}.$$

Sorry for asking such a vague question.

Edit: Am I correct in assuming this is the substitution I need to make?:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28x^2%2Ba%29^%28-3%2F2%29

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solely about performing a standard integral.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to calculate the electric field due to a line charge distribution at a perpendicular distance z from mid-point of the rod.
The given integral can be solved by taking x=z tan(theta). 
But to observe the physics behind it, in figure draw the triangle and observe where is this theta such that tan(theta)=x/z.
Now instead of taking elemental length dx consider elemental angle d(theta), and the solve the problem.
You will observe that the field at the given point P, comes out to be same as that of a semicircle(of radius z) with same charge distribution centered at the point P.
Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Put $x=z\tan \theta {}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$